# How can I get the ip address of the local system in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to capture the IP address of the local system.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the IP address of the user?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this to find local ip address not a public ip address

```js
 var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})
findIP.then(function(ip) {
console.log(ip);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code on your project

```
this.http.get("http://api.ipify.org/?format=json").subscribe((res:any)=>{

  this.ipAddress = res.ip;

});
```